# How should I account for small samples in a larger data set? Should I remove them?

Tags: statistical-significance, small-sample

We're trying to develop a simple tool that will help our teams optimise their clients' Facebook posting strategies. In our experience, time of post can have a big impact on audience response; but those times will differ from audience to audience based on their behaviours (can they access Facebook from work? What times of day are they online? When are they at a loose end, and when are other activities taking up their concentration?) We expect responsiveness to vary throughout the day for these (and other known & unknown) reasons. Furthermore, of course, time of day isn't the only reason that response rates vary; the content of the post is one very significant reason.

I don't know if this background is useful; whether it makes the following question clearer.

The following R script (I lack sufficient reputation to post charts) contains data that cover posting activity and audience response by hour of post. You'll notice that the 6 am point (for which we have two observations) massively outperforms the rest of the day. We often see these very high response rates for hours that have fewer observations.

```r
post.hour <- c(0:23)
posts <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 15, 16, 10, 17, 13, 29, 21, 23, 
           18, 29, 24, 34, 42, 51, 48, 49, 17)
response <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5282, 8627, 6080, 2716, 2831, 
              3258, 6291, 7756, 4008, 4614, 11838, 2611, 10527, 
              14706, 5416, 10970, 19098, 9505)
mean.response <- response/posts

d <- data.frame(post.hour, posts, response, mean.response)

library(ggplot2)

response.chart <- ggplot(d,aes(post.hour,mean.response)) +
 geom_point() + geom_line() +
 ylab("mean response") +
 opts (title="mean audience response by post hour")
response.chart
```

I've tried manually removing hours that have fewer than a certain number of observations:

This seems unsatisfactory, and (furthermore) is hard to automate across widely differing data sets.

1. Should I remove these hours? If so, what statistical tools should I use to perform this repeatedly and automatically across multiple data sets?
2. If the answer is "no" -- and I suspect that it might be -- what should I do to account for these tiny sample sizes?

Conscious that this is possibly Statistics 101 stuff. It should be clear from this that I have not - in fact - had any statistical training. I'd greatly appreciate you taking this into account if and when you respond to this question. I'm not even sure that the hourly data represent samples ...

Comment: I don't really understand your question. In your supplied code, is each row a "sample" or a "data point"? Typically it is the latter, but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Also, removing rows that make no sense is standard procedure. Are you worried about the `NaN` fields in `d`? if so, you can remove them automatically with `d.stripped <- d[which(is.na(d$mean.response) == FALSE).]`

Comment: @gmacfarlane I wasn't particularly concerned by the NaN fields (ggplot2 seems to strip them automatically) because it's relatively useful for me to visualise a full day's worth of activity, and not simply the active period. Replacing them with zeroes seems to be a bad idea, too. I think I should probably replace them with NA?

Comment: @gmacfarlane your other question is very useful I think. I have to confess my ignorance:  I don't know enough to use the terms properly. I think these are actually data points. The data supplied above are actually already the product of some cleaning and analysis. I could supply the raw data as a Google Spreadsheet; would that make this question clearer?

Comment: what does "response" mean? Is this the number of members of the public who "like" what your client has posted, or something like that?

Comment: You are effectively looking at the relationship between number of posts and response, mediated by hour.  Best way is a model that can have number of posts, and hour of day, as explanatory variables and response as the response variable.  By looking at the mean you are forcing this model to have an intercept through zero.  The fact is that the "response" depends not so simply on posts.  Try qplot(posts, response, label=post.hour, color=post.hour, geom="text",data=d) + geom_smooth(method="lm") for an alternative....

Comment: ...If you want to do what you are setting out to though I think you need more data, including multiple days worth of data, and response by sub-audience.

Comment: @PeterEllis thank you for your questions and suggestions: while this wasn't really _about_ R (I just assume -- possibly incorrectly -- that everyone here has a copy) I learned a couple of neat new things from your `qplot`.

Comment: @PeterEllis However, the plot now only really tells me that the more observations we take ("posts") the more responses (you're correct in assuming that these are "likes", "comments" and "shares") we observe.

These observations (the 458 posts) were made over an ~190 day period; at ~2.5 posts per day, this is a surprisingly high post frequency when compared to most Facebook Pages.

Comment: If you've got the full 190 days of data ie number of responses in each hour of each day, and also the number of your posts in that timeslot, you could do a generalized linear model with a Poisson family response, with number of posts and time of day as the two explanatory variables - and sub-audience type as a third, if you have that information.